# Pie Chart: color issue

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am happily playing with the [colored pie chart](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart-color/) nicely shared by Henri Menke. I have adapted it a bit to my needs. However, there is still a glitch when I want to color the `\percent` or the `\name` entries. See below: I am trying to achieve this using the `text={\color}` option (see the instances "WARNING") to color the text in question with the current color `\color`. However, it goes mad and I do not understand why. Note that `\textcolor{\color}{\name}` does not help. This is strange because the options `fill={\color!50}` or `draw={\color}` work nicely.

```
% Pie chart with colors
% Author: Henri Menke
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green","black","pink"}}
\newcount\cyclecount
\cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind
\ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[cap=round,join=round]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      20/term 1,
      20/term 2,
      20/term 3,
      20/term 4,
      20/term 5,
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum5<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw=white] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius) arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node[text={\color}] at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.8*\radius) {\percent}; % WARNING
        \draw (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius)--(\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:1.2*\radius)node[circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,text={\color}]{\name}; % WARNING
        \filldraw (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) circle (1pt);
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: piechart]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your final result should look like, but does renaming `\color` to e.g. `\mycolor` help?

Comment: well, we should not read all the doubled color terms like "blackblack" or "greengreen"... About `\mycolor`, yes, it does the trick! Cannot believe it. Please provide an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's not a good idea to redefine `\color` (which already exists to set the text color). Use a different name, e.g. `\mycolor`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green","black","pink"}}
\newcount\cyclecount
\cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind
\ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[cap=round,join=round]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      20/term 1,
      20/term 2,
      20/term 3,
      20/term 4,
      20/term 5,
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum5<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\mycolor{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \mycolor
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\mycolor!50},draw=white] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius) arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
        \node[text={\mycolor}] at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:0.8*\radius) {\percent}; % WARNING
        \draw (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius)--(\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:1.2*\radius)node[circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,text={\mycolor}]{\name}; % WARNING
        \filldraw (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) circle (1pt);
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree but `\color` (redefined) was used in the original example by someone very knowledgeable in Latex so I did not think it was an issue.